# Nvidia graphic not working fine in battery mode

Tags: nvidia, graphics, power-management, battery, tlp

I installed Nvidia graphic driver from "Additional Drivers" on my laptop. Everything works fine in **AC Mode**. when I switch to **Battery Mode** the system starts to lag.
I tried to overcome this issue with manipulating TLP configuration settings for battery mode, But I could not.

Please notice that everything is working fine in AC & Battery mode with **X.Org x server-Nouveau**.

Laptop : Lenovo z510

OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Graphic version : Nvidia Geforce 740M

**What should I do ?**

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia driver may be throttling , can you check the nvidia control panel if there is any option for setting performance.

Comment: I checked it out. Performance option had been selected. not affected on battery.

Comment: Not too sure then